# How to Search 100,000 Edges Fast?

Tags: python, search, graph

I have a network DirectedGraph object `G` that contains around 2,0000 vertices and 120,000 edges in it.

I'd like to search the edge list and check which edge ends in the vertex 'deny'.(Oh the graph vertices are all an English word.)

I've just stupidly does as following, but it never stops.. I am waiting more than 10 mins from the very beginning.

How could I perform it fast?

```
 for i in range(len(G.edges())):
    if list(G.edges())[i][1] == 'deny':
        print(list(G.edges())[i])
```

Comment: I think just intuitively thinking, I should search every element in the list to check whether a edge finished in "deny".. so might be there's no other options to make it fast other than look up every element linearly..?

Answer (score 0):

You can have dictionary of `<end vertex, (start vertex, end)>`. However, it depends on how frequent these operations would be performed.

If it's just one time operation then I would just go about looping my list otherwise implement the dictionary.